# CSS3 Fade Bottom of <section>

Tags: css, background, background-image, linear-gradients

I have been searching high and low, but I have not found a **CSS3** method for using a `linear-gradient` to fade the bottom of a `<section>` tag to white.

If I'm not being clear, let me illustrate this with an example. If I have a `<section>` tag which is full of lots of text, I would like the text to be cut off at a designated height. To show that there is still more text to be read, the container would display a white gradient which partially covers the last line or so to show that there is more text to read.

I know that this can be done with PNGs or GIFs, but I don't know how to do this with CSS3. Could someone provide an example?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do it the same way you'd do with PNGs or GIFs, but switch out the PNG/GIF image for a linear gradient? It doesn't get any simpler than that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with an extra element and some JavaScript. Like this:

```css
#some-section {
    position: relative;
}

#some-section .after {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 20px; /* Whatever suits you */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var section = document.getElementById('some-section');
var after = document.createElement('div');
after.className = 'after';

section.appendChild(after);

section.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    after.style.bottom = -section.scrollTop + 'px';
}, false);​
```

[Here's a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/VHw5E/)

Comment: Just out of curiosity will the `::after` psuedo-element work for any browser that supports linear gradients?

Comment: @spryno724: Sorry, not quite. The `::after` element scrolls with it... lemme just fix that.

Comment: I'm a little confused - is there a demo for this working with a `::after` pseudo element or are you saying that it is not possible? Thanks!

Comment: @sguha: No, it's not possible with `::after`, it seems. The JavaScript one is the only way I could get to work.

Comment: @minitech Actually I was able to get it to work, basically using your code. Thanks for your answer! http://jsfiddle.net/sguha095/VHw5E/11/

Comment: @sguha: The problem, though, is that it scrolls with the container. At least, it does on Chrome. (But if it works for your purposes - excellent! :D)

Comment: Oh, you're right, thanks for pointing that out. In my purposes I have a toggle to hide/show the rest of the content so it's ok, but for the original question, your solution is correct.

Comment: How could you edit this to make the fade disappear as you reach the bottom of the text?